# Are there any books/portions of books/particular topics of study that go into great detail to describe the physics of a rope (or any ropelike body)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, string, continuum-mechanics

I don't know why, but lately, I can't get the physics of a rope of my mind, specifically what happens to a coiled, or otherwise not taught/pulled straight rope when it is pulled taught. I don't really know if its useful in any way but I cant't get it off the brain.

for example, here's a couple of laid out ropes. I think it would interesting how to describe each point on the rope as the ends of the rope are pulled outward and made taught.

[image]

These are just some simple 2D examples, things would get pretty complex when ropes are allowed to overlap and are also given a width.

I tried googling for any resources on this but I couldnt find any (I did find a cool article on ["Liquid Rope-Coil Effect"](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.1996110) though). So I was wondering if anyone knew of some sources that went into detail on this subject or anytging similar, if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuum mechanics, but it has too many topics except for the rope. The principals are the same.
Besides, there does exist some books about rope only. Such as *Theory of wire rope* . Just try googling with **book about rope/wire/string mechanics** and you will find more.
I did some research about this before and if you are into codes, youcan find some programs in github for rope modelling, which maybe helpful to you to understand the numerical approach to deal with the rope.(finite element analysis of course)